# email real time component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

I'm trying to create a mailbox component in order to get the real-time data displayed in my mailbox component I use trumbowyg for creating the WYSIWYG editor and bootstrap  but I can't manage to get it real-time

```
<script type="text/babel">
    var Modal = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
          return (
            <div className="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" ><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 className="modal-title">{this.props.title}</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    {this.props.body}
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-footer">
                    <div className="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
                      <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger outline" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="clearfix" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );s
        }
    });
    var Editor = React.createClass({
      getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
          body: "",
          placeholder: "Enter your message here..."
        };
      },
      componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.body == ""){
          $('#editor').trumbowyg('empty');
        }
      },
      componentDidMount: function () {
        var that = this;
        $('#editor').trumbowyg({
          fullscreenable: false
        })
        .on('tbwchange', function (){
          that.props.onChange($('#editor').trumbowyg('html'));
        });
        $('#editor').trumbowyg('html', this.props.body);
      },
      render: function () {
        return <div id="editor" placeholder={this.props.placeholder} ></div>;
      }
    });
    var Mailbox = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function () {
        return {
          "emailTo": "",
          "emailCC": "",
          "emailBCC": "",
          "emailSubject": "",
          "emailBody": ""
        }
      },
      render: function () {
        return (
          <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-8 center">
                  <div className="inbox-title">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope center"></span>
                    <h2 className="center">{this.props.title}</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-4 center">
                  <div className="inbox-avatar text-right">
                    <img src={this.props.urlImage} />
                    <div className="inbox-avatar-name"><a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.username}</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12">
                  <form className="form-horizontal">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email-to" className="col-sm-1 control-label">To</label>
                      <div className="col-sm-11">
                        <input type="email"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="email-to"
                                value={this.state.emailTo}
                                placeholder="Ex: hello@example.com"
                                onChange={this.handleEmailToChange}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email-cc" className="col-sm-1 control-label">CC</label>
                      <div className="col-sm-11">
                        <input type="email"
                              className="form-control"
                              id="email-cc"
                              value={this.state.emailCC}
                              onChange={this.handleEmailCCChange}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email-bcc" className="col-sm-1 control-label">BCC</label>
                      <div className="col-sm-11">
                        <input type="email"
                               className="form-control"
                               id="email-bcc"
                               value={this.state.emailBCC}
                               onChange={this.handleEmailBCCChange}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email-subject" className="col-sm-1 control-label">Subject</label>
                      <div className="col-sm-11">
                        <input type="email"
                               className="form-control"
                               id="email-subject"
                               value={this.state.emailSubject}
                               onChange={this.handleEmailSubjectChange}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="panel-body">
              <Editor onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
                      body={this.state.emailBody} />
            </div>
            <div className="panel-footer">
              <div className="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
                <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.handleCancelClick} className="btn btn-danger">CANCEL</button>
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSaveClick} className="btn btn-success">SAVE</button>
                </div>
                <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSendClick} className="btn btn-primary outline">SEND</button>
                </div>
                <Modal ref="modalSend" title="Email sent!" body="Your email has been successfully sent!" />
                <Modal ref="modalSave" title="Email saved!" body="Your email has been successfully saved!" />
              </div>
              <div className="clearfix" />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
      handleEditorChange: function (emailBody) {
        this.setState({ "emailBody": emailBody });
      },
      handleEmailToChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ "emailTo": e.target.value });
      },
      handleEmailCCChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ "emailCC": e.target.value });
      },
      handleEmailBCCChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ "emailBCC": e.target.value });
      },
      handleEmailSubjectChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ "emailSubject": e.target.value });
      },
      handleCancelClick: function () {
        this.setState({
          "emailTo": "",
          "emailCC": "",
          "emailBCC": "",
          "emailSubject": "",
          "emailBody": ""
        });
      },
      handleSaveClick: function () {
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.modalSave)).modal();
      },
      handleSendClick: function () {
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.modalSend)).modal();
      }
    });
    var options = {
      username: "Michel lompret",
      link: "https://google.com",
      urlImage: "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1",
      title: "React Mailbox Editor"
    };
    var element = React.createElement(Mailbox, options);
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
  </script>
```

Is there a way to get back my gmail or outlook mails in my mailbox component and send email from it like a real time app ?

Answer (score 0):

From their docs....
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

You would need to setup a watch, then callback when your watch changes...

Also from their docs....
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync

Comment: watch? thinking in angularjs?

Comment: The Gmail API provides server push notifications that let you watch for changes to Gmail mailboxes. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed. Whenever a mailbox changes, the Gmail API notifies your backend server application.

Comment: That’s directly from the link I posted. Do you have a backend ?

Comment: Yeah well. So if he has to implement something like sockets, dont you think you should clarify that first? :)